# ReactJs.NET webpackJsonp is not defined in server side rendering

Tags: .net, reactjs, webpack, reactjs.net, commonschunkplugin

I have been following along the guide to make Webpack work with React.NET (at https://reactjs.net/guides/webpack.html), and one of my requirements is to have third party libraries in a separate bundle. For this, I've made use of the CommonsChunkPlugin found at https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/.

Trying this setup with client side rendering seems to work alright, but can't still figure out how to do the same for server side rendering. I would always see the error `Error while loading "~/Scripts/build/bundle.js": ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined`.

I'm fairly new to this Webpack world, but managed to realize that `webpackJsonp` variable is registered at the `window` level, which I'm guessing the server side rendering engines have no access to. Is this the case? Is there any workarounds for this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I've managed to get it working by separating the webpack configuration into a client oriented one (including code splitting), and a server oriented one, following the suggestions found in the original thread: https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/392 .

Hope it helps the next one!